# Rspec: How to test ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I'm using raw/bare-metal sql inserts to increase write performance on my service. I have something like this in my module -

```
insert = "('#{id}', '#{status}', '#{some_time_val}')"
sql_string = "INSERT INTO history ('device_id', 'status', 'time') VALUES #{insert}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql_string
```

When I write an rspec like below, it tests everything except whether or not the insert went through. So my expectations will never work because of the way rspec, database_cleaner etc do rollbacks and transactions. 
I tried using

```
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

and

```
  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
  end
```

but the inserts still don't go through to my test database

```
describe Worker do
  let (:device1) {FactoryGirl.create(:device)}
  let (:device2) {FactoryGirl.create(:device)}
  let (:device3) {FactoryGirl.create(:device)}
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
  end

  it "does something" do
    devices = [{"status" => "Offline", "time" => "2013-09-17 18:17:17", "id" => device1.id},
                {"status" => "Online", "time" => "2013-09-17 18:18:18", "id" => device2.id}]
    Worker.any_instance.stubs(:devices).returns(devices) ## Not important for this question
    Worker.new.perform

    device1.reload.status.should == "Offline" # FAILS
  end

end
```

How would I test this? What's a good strategy to test raw sql inserts like this?

Comment: You definitely don’t want no database cleaning. At the least you want truncation. No cleaning means test pollution. Also note that your query has a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't be able to test this "normally" (and I think database cleaner is a red herring). Do your tests pass if you use normal active record rather than `execute` (It seems curious to me that you are reloading an existing object to test its status whereas the snippet you posted seems to insert a new row into a different table)

Comment: What is the output when you run the query on sandbox console? It appears to me that your query is missing a final ';'.

Comment: In general this workflow is testable. I recommend to verify your SQL directly in your DB. Maybe you need to use grave characters instead of appostrophs (\`device_id\` instead of 'device_id')... it depends on your SQL engine.

Answer (score 7):

There are two schools of thought about how to properly test code: the 'methods' perspective is about ensuring your own correct behavior, and the 'results' perspective favors checking results.  I'll provide both perspectives.

**Methods:**

You did not write `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and you are not responsible for it working correctly.  Your test, then, can focus on what you passed into the execute method.  A matching spec, then, might look something like this.

```
connection = double("Connection")
expect(ActiveRecord::Base).to receive(:connection) { connection }
expect(connection).to receive(:execute).with("...")
Worker.new.perform
```

where ... is the SQL that you intend to generate.  Verifying the SQL works appropriately might be done somewhere else, or not done at all, depending on your taste.  This assures you (and future devs) that the correct instruction has been delivered to your database.

**Results:**

This approach doesn't find reassurance in what approach is taken, it finds reassurance in outcomes.  It is the approach you are taking in the above examples.

You don't show us what the `perform` method looks like above, so we're not sure if, perhaps, there is a problem with your implementation code, as opposed to the `reload` mechanism you're using to prompt ActiveRecord to notice your changes.  ActiveRecord has a variety of performance enhancements designed to cloud direct binding between the database contents and what you are able to access in your Ruby VM's object graph.  You can struggle with trying to override this behavior if you like, but if you're content to use ActiveRecord directly in your implementation, perhaps you are also content to do so in your tests?

```
d1_status = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT status from history where id = #{device1.id} limit 1;").values[0][0]
expect(d1_status).to eq("Offline")
```

I note some troubling inferences here, though.  You are editing the `history` table, but expecting results from what's presumably a `Device` model.  The implementation of the `status` method then is also relevant to your problem.  You may wish to write additional tests for the `Device#status` method, if you select this approach.